# get birthdays of three consecutive days and convert to dd-mm format

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have written MySql query to find today,tomorrow and yesterday's birthday which looks something like this

```
SELECT Emp_Name,Emp_DOB  FROM mldob.tbl_mldob
WHERE  
(MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()-1))
OR
(MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()))
OR
(MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()+1))
;
```

and it gives the result in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format and `Emp_DOB` is of the type `datetime` format but i need result as `dd-month` eg: `31-oct`

can anybody provide solution how to achieve this and the above query is it correct to find today,tomorrow and yesterday's birthday??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Removed `SQL SERVER` tag. `NOW()` is a `MYSQL` function

Comment: you can use `DATE()` to extract the date part. `SELECT ..., DATE(Emp_DOB)....`

Comment: DATE() function will return the date in yyyy-mm-dd format but i need in dd-month eg: 31-oct

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you asked for `dd-mm` only @HeenaRamesh

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)` function in order to format the date

I've also tried to rewrite the query.

Here's another way of achieving this:

```
SELECT 
Emp_Name,
DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB,'%d-%b') AS dob
FROM mldob.tbl_mldob
WHERE  
    DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB,'%m-%d') IN (
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d'),
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d'),
      DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%m-%d')
  )
```

**Note:**

```
%d  Day of month, numeric (00-31)
%b  Abbreviated month name (Jan-Dec)
```

See more <kbd>[**DATE_FORMAT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)</kbd>

Comment: thanks this works absolutely fine for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Emp_Name, date_format(Emp_DOB, '%d-%b') AS Emp_DOB  FROM mldob.tbl_mldob WHERE  
(MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()-1))
OR
(MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()))
OR
(MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()+1))
;
```

More reference:
[MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: and tnx all for solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query gives you the result required, but just not formatted to your needs, you can format it like this using [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT Emp_Name,
       DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB, "%d-%b") 
FROM   mldob.tbl_mldob
WHERE  
    (MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()-1))
    OR
    (MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()))
    OR
    (MONTH(Emp_DOB ), DAY(Emp_DOB )) = (MONTH(NOW()),DAY(curdate()+1))
;
```

However, your query won't work properly if you run across the changeover of a month, since the conditions don't give you a day from last or next month.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT Emp_Name,
       DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB, "%d-%b") 
FROM   mldob.tbl_mldob
WHERE  
    DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Emp_DOB,'2000-%m-%d')) BETWEEN 
        (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'2000-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND
        (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'2000-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d - %b')
```

Where `%d` is date  and `%b` is month name.